# Old Bob is ill : Said Grandpa

Tags: knowledge, lateral-thinking, alphametic

“Darn good computer, this new one I just got. So you can have my old one”, said Grandpa to my sister.

I was impressed, but a bit cynical. “What’s the catch?”

Grandpa smiled. “Just guess the 4 letter password; unlock the computer and it is hers!”

I knew it. Another silly riddle.

“Tell you what. I will give you a clue”, said Grandpa.

“Are you sure one will do it?”

“Listen to this guy. OK 2 clues.”

> **Old Bob is ill**. Add those words, like an alphametic, and you have
> your password!

“Fine. But it’s not a full alphametic, is it? Give me a second clue.”

> “OK. The password is an Indian word.”

“Native American Indian or Hindi?”

“They both have it son”, said Grandpa, and he disappeared.

*What is the password and how can one get it from that sentence?*

> Hint:
>
> There is a clue in the format of the puzzle itself

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The hint nicely tells about:

> **DIGITAL FONT**, as you can read from the first letter of each lines.

Applying that to the **Old Bob is ill**, we get this:

> [image]

Do you see what's special about this?

> If you rotate it 180 degrees, you will see the numbers. :)
>
>  [image]

So:

> $$771+51+808+070=1700$$

And the password is:

> <s>OOLI</s> **DOLI**, by rotating it 180 degrees!

Comment: VERY close. OOLI is NOT an Indian word, I do not think.@athin

Comment: @DEEM Oh, I just barely googled that (OOLI) and found some Hindi words about that, but alright, how about this [new answer](http://www.ourbabynamer.com/meaning-of-Doli.html)?

Comment: That is it! The word means Bluebird in Navajo Indian speaks and a wedding chair in Hindi

Comment: Yep as an Indian I can confirm that fact. +1 to both question and answer.

Comment: @Lakshay Sura rot13(Qbyv fnwnxr enxunan-- jung n fbat)

Comment: @DEEM If "grandpa" loves Bollywood songs, I would love him but oh there I love him anyway. Great puzzle as I was confused where to use alphametic.